# Simple vue app doesn't show anything

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Full code: https://github.com/kenpeter/test_vue_template

```
git clone https://github.com/kenpeter/test_vue_template
```

install: `yarn install`

run: `yarn dev`

visit `localhost:8080` and see nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't render anything in your root component.

In your `index.html`, render the `app` component:

```
<div id="app">
  <app></app>
</div>
```

There are several ways to do this. If you don't want to touch your `index.html`, you can also modify the `main.js`. All of the code below should work:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  components: {
    App
  }
})
```

or

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {
    App
  }
})
```